# lvalue required as left operand of assignment - Array

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

Below is the snippet of code where the error lies, the line

```
a[i][j] = m[i][j] + w[i][j];
```

returns an error

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

I can't find an answer that applies to arrays, my Matrix is defined as follows:

```
Matrix::Matrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            coords[i][j] = 0.0f;
}

const Matrix operator+(const Matrix &m, const Matrix &w) {
    Matrix a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4 ; j++)
            a[i][j] = m[i][j] + w[i][j];  // <----- error
    return a;
}
```

Here is the operator[] 
How do I return by reference

```
const Vector Matrix::operator[](int i) const{
    switch(i)
    {
    case 0: return Vector (coords[i][0], coords[i][1], coords[i][2]);
    case 1: return Vector (coords[i][0], coords[i][1], coords[i][2]);
    case 2: return Vector (coords[i][0], coords[i][1], coords[i][2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your error fully. problem with operator

Comment: And `Matrix::operator[]`

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you initialize the matrix as 3x3 but access it as 3x4? Why not writing a template with `<int COLS, int ROWS>`?

Answer (score 13):

The error is actually "**lvalue** required as left operand of assignment".

It means that your `a[i][j]` is giving you a temporary object. This happens when you return from a function by value. A function call that returns by value is an *rvalue* expression, and you cannot use an rvalue expression as the left operand of an assignment. You need to change the implementation of `operator[]` on both the `Matrix` and the helper class that `Matrix::operator[]` returns so that they return by reference. A function call that returns by reference is an lvalue expression and will allow you to assign to it.

```
template <typename T>
Vector<T>& Matrix<T>::operator[](int index) { ... }
template <typename T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](int index) { ... }
```

Of course, this makes sense. If your `operator[]`s didn't return by reference, how would assigning to the value returned by them have any effect on the contents of the `Matrix`?

---

In response to your edit:

You have a problem with the design of your class. The `Matrix` class appears to store a 3-by-3 array of `float`s called `coords`. However, when you use `Matrix::operator[]`, it copies the values from a row of `coords` into a `Vector` object. They are *copies*. You then return that `Vector` by value, which copies the `Vector` and its contained values out of the function. Anything you do to that returned `Vector` will only affect that copy.

In addition to this, your `switch` statement is totally pointless. Every case is exactly the same. You just need to use `i` as the array indices and not switch on it.

Also, if you're going to allow people that call `operator[]` to modify the contents of your `Matrix`, then the `operator[]` function must not be `const`.

There are a few alternatives that will fix your problem. The first is to just return a `float*` instead and scrap your plan with `Vector`:

```
float* Matrix::operator[](int i) {
    return coords[i];
}
```

That's a very simple solution but does involve passing a raw pointer around. The raw pointer can be used like an array, allowing you the syntax `m[i][j]`.

You could do the same as the Eigen library and instead provide a `operator()` that takes two arguments, the row index and column index:

```
float& Matrix::operator()(int i, int j) {
    return coords[i][j];
}
```

Note that the `float` is being returned by reference: `float&`. This means that is modifiable from outside the call to `operator()`. Here, you would index a row and column with `m(i, j)`.

Comment: @DavidSmith Exactly, your `operator[]` returns `const Vector` which will not only copy the `Vector` into a temporary object, but that temporary object will be `const`. You have no hope of assigning to it. Your function should instead return a `Vector&` (not `const`!).

Answer (score 1):

it means your `[]` operator returns a value without an address that cannot be used for assignment. Its straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

What is `Vector`?

The problem probably starts with what `Matrix::operator[]`
returns.  For the `[][]` syntax to work, it *must* return some
sort of proxy, to which the second `[]` can be applied, and it
will return a reference to the desired element in the matrix.
The usual way of doing this (at least for me) is to define
a "setter" and "getter" in `Matrix`:

```
void set( int i, int j, double new_value )
{
    myData[ getIndex( i, j ) ] = new_value;
}

double get( int i, int j ) const
{
    return myData[ getIndex( i, j ) ];
}
```

and then make use of two proxies (nested classes in Matrix):

```
class Proxy2D
{
    Matrix* myOwner;
    int myIndex1;
    int myIndex2;
public:
    Proxy2D( Matrix& owner, int index1, int index2 )
        : myOwner( &owner )
        , myIndex1( index1 )
        , myIndex2( index2 )
    {
    }
    void operator=( double new_value ) const
    {
        myOwner->set( myIndex1, myIndex2, new_value ):
    }
    operator double() const
    {
        return myOwner->get( myIndex1, myIndex2 );
    }
};

class Proxy1D
{
    Matrix* myOwner;
    int myIndex;
public:
    Proxy1D( Matrix& owner, int index )
        : myOwner( &owner )
        , myIndex( index )
    {
    }
    Proxy2D operator[]( int index2 ) const
    {
        return Proxy2D( *myOwner, myIndex, index2 );
    }
};

Proxy1D operator[]( int index1 )
{
    return Proxy1D( *this, index1 );
}
```

In practice, you'll want const variants as well, to be returned
by `operator[]( int index1 ) const`.  And of course,
`ConstProxy2D` won't need the overload for `operator=`; the
implicit conversion is sufficient.

And in case it isn't obvious, `Matrix::getIndex` does the bounds
checking, and then calculates the actual index in the underlying
`std::vector<double>` which contains the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you return a newly constructed `Vector` object to represent a column (or row, doesn't really matter), this Vector is responsible to update an entry in the original Matrix instance, which is a little bit tricky but can easily be solved:

You have to implement another `VectorRef` class which doesn't represent a vector by value but by reference and can thus be used to access the components as **lvalues**. This means, that it doesn't contain the numbers as values but as reference and takes these references in its constructor. To keep things simple, you can use a pointer which points to the first component (followed by the other components):

```
class VectorRef {
    float *coords;
public:
    VectorRef(float *coords) : coords(coords) {}
    float & operator[](int i) { return coords[i]; }
};
```

Then, construct such a "reference object" in the `operator[]` of the matrix:

```
VectorRef Matrix::operator[](int i) {
    return VectorRef (coords[i]);
}
```

To use the `VectorRef` also as a `Vector`, provide a conversion operator:

```
    // (within VectorRef:)
    operator Vector() const { return Vector(coords[0], coords[1], coords[2]); }
```

This should make things seemless.

Alternatively, if you always access the elements within a matrix and not columns as a whole, just return the column pointer directly in the `operator[]` of the matrix:

```
float * Matrix::operator[](int i) {
    return coords[i];
}
```

When writing `mat[x][y]`, this will first access the float pointer with `mat[x]` and then accesses the `y`-th element of that column, which is an **lvalue**.