# assignment of a multidimensional array element -- lvalue required?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, lvalue, square-bracket

To store images that can me more than two-dimensional, I use a class that has data members

```
std::vector <size_t> sizes;    // dimensions of the images
std::vector <size_t> strides;  // strides to walk through the data
std::vector <double> *data;    // data points stored as 1-dimensional
```

and to get and set the values individual points I have these functions

```
// operator[] for positional addressing
double const* operator[] ( std::initializer_list < size_t > const& indices ) const {
   size_t const offset =
          std::inner_product ( indices.begin(), indices.end(),
                               strides.begin(),
                               0 );
   return & ( (*data) [ offset ] );
}
double* operator[] ( std::initializer_list < size_t > const& indices ) {
   size_t const offset =
          std::inner_product ( indices.begin(), indices.end(),
                               strides.begin(),
                               0 );
   return & ( (*data) [ offset ] );
}
```

I can use these functions to get the data at specified positions and print them, *e.g.* using `std::cout << my_image[{1,2,3}]` for a 3D image, but when I want to set them, *e.g.* using `my_image[{1,2,3}] = 10.;` then I get the error `lvalue required as left operand as assignment`. I followed the advice of [ean earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832847) by passing pointers from the `[]`operator (which itself is by value), one const and one non-const. Should it not possible to set image elements with this syntax as well?

Comment: Why is `data` a pointer to vector? A vector already has a pointer to the data inside of it. Just remove the pointer and return `double& operator[]` i.e. a reference. And the const version can simply return `double`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Must admit it can be confusing to the untrained eye (went to your solution via `invalid initialization of non-const reference`). I had a pointer to the vector to do `new` and `delete` but probably `std::vector`'s own methods are cleaner!